# Validate Email and IP

Tags: php, validation, email, ip

I'm using the following code to check if submitted emails and ip's are valid, I'm using the following code:

```
class Engine {
    function validateEmail($email) {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function validateIP($ip) {
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, is this a good way of validating a users email/ip?

Comment: You should ask such questions at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry, will do - Kinda new here :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This is better suited to the **[Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is okay, you can make it shorter, because filter_var returns true/false:

```
function validateEmail($email) {    
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}    

function validateIP($ip) {
    return filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6);
}
```